# Transforming an array to a string containing that array using jolt

Tags: java, json, avro, jolt

This is my source input json

```
{
  "payload": {
    "keys": {
      "sce0_client_num": 101,
      "sce0_application_num": -5493929203645992000,
      "sce0_application_suffix": 101
    },
    "sce0_segment_length": 101,
    "sce0_behavior_scores": [
      {
        "sce0_triad_score_raw": 101,
        "sce0_triad_score_aligned": 101,
        "sce0_triad_scorecard_id": 101,
        "sce0_date_behavior_scores": -1319636323
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_score_raw": 52645188,
        "sce0_triad_score_aligned": -1856889773,
        "sce0_triad_scorecard_id": 101,
        "sce0_date_behavior_scores": 101
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_score_raw": 1,
        "sce0_triad_score_aligned": -11,
        "sce0_triad_scorecard_id": 101,
        "sce0_date_behavior_scores": 101
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_score_raw": 2,
        "sce0_triad_score_aligned": -22,
        "sce0_triad_scorecard_id": 102,
        "sce0_date_behavior_scores": 102
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_score_raw": 3,
        "sce0_triad_score_aligned": -33,
        "sce0_triad_scorecard_id": 103,
        "sce0_date_behavior_scores": 103
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_score_raw": 4,
        "sce0_triad_score_aligned": -44,
        "sce0_triad_scorecard_id": 104,
        "sce0_date_behavior_scores": 104
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_score_raw": 5,
        "sce0_triad_score_aligned": -55,
        "sce0_triad_scorecard_id": 105,
        "sce0_date_behavior_scores": 105
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_score_raw": 6,
        "sce0_triad_score_aligned": -66,
        "sce0_triad_scorecard_id": 106,
        "sce0_date_behavior_scores": 106
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_score_raw": 7,
        "sce0_triad_score_aligned": -77,
        "sce0_triad_scorecard_id": 107,
        "sce0_date_behavior_scores": 107
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_score_raw": 8,
        "sce0_triad_score_aligned": -88,
        "sce0_triad_scorecard_id": 108,
        "sce0_date_behavior_scores": 108
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_score_raw": 9,
        "sce0_triad_score_aligned": -99,
        "sce0_triad_scorecard_id": 109,
        "sce0_date_behavior_scores": 109
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_score_raw": 10,
        "sce0_triad_score_aligned": -100,
        "sce0_triad_scorecard_id": 111,
        "sce0_date_behavior_scores": 111
      }
    ],
    "sce0_credit_score_org": 1720785150,
    "sce0_mds_auth_score": 101,
    "sce0_mds_coll_score": 101,
    "sce0_cb_score_data": [
      {
        "sce0_cb_score": -326862643,
        "sce0_date_cb_score": 1271544989
      },
      {
        "sce0_cb_score": -1664695633,
        "sce0_date_cb_score": 101
      },
      {
        "sce0_cb_score": 1340696727,
        "sce0_date_cb_score": -1830228389
      },
      {
        "sce0_cb_score": 101,
        "sce0_date_cb_score": 337343512
      },
      {
        "sce0_cb_score": 102,
        "sce0_date_cb_score": 55555
      },
      {
        "sce0_cb_score": 103,
        "sce0_date_cb_score": 6666
      },
      {
        "sce0_cb_score": 104,
        "sce0_date_cb_score": 7777
      }
    ],
    "sce0_cb_worst_public_record": 2024061225,
    "sce0_cb_worst_trade_line": -506011687,
    "sce0_cb_number_trade_lines": 2000451889,
    "sce0_cb_number_disputed_lines": 834290474,
    "sce0_triad_batch_auth_cntr": 101,
    "sce0_triad_blaze_advisor": [
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 1
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": -2
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 3
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 4
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 5
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 6
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 7
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 8
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 9
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 10
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 11
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 12
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 13
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 14
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 15
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 16
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 17
      },
      {
        "sce0_triad_blaze_score": 18
      }
    ],
    "sce0_cb_score_data_2": [
      {
        "sce0_cb_score_2": -326862643,
        "sce0_date_cb_score_2": 1271544989
      },
      {
        "sce0_cb_score_2": -1664695633,
        "sce0_date_cb_score_2": 101
      },
      {
        "sce0_cb_score_2": 1340696727,
        "sce0_date_cb_score_2": -1830228389
      },
      {
        "sce0_cb_score_2": 101,
        "sce0_date_cb_score_2": 337343512
      },
      {
        "sce0_cb_score_2": 102,
        "sce0_date_cb_score_2": 55555
      }
    ],
    "sce0_custom_char_field": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6,
      7,
      8,
      9,
      10,
      11,
      12,
      13,
      14,
      15,
      16
    ],
    "sce0_custom_numeric_field": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6,
      7,
      8,
      9,
      10,
      11,
      12,
      13,
      14,
      15,
      16,
      17,
      18,
      19,
      20,
      21,
      22,
      23,
      24,
      25,
      26,
      27,
      28,
      29,
      30,
      31,
      32,
      33,
      34,
      35,
      36,
      37,
      38
    ],
    "sce0_custom_numeric_field_33": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6,
      7,
      8,
      9,
      10,
      11,
      12,
      13,
      14,
      15,
      16,
      17,
      18,
      19,
      20,
      21,
      22,
      23,
      24,
      25,
      26,
      27,
      28,
      29,
      30,
      31,
      32,
      33
    ],
    "sce0_pmax_score_dollar_val_01": "iiiiiii",
    "sce0_pmax_score_dollar_val_02": "ooooo",
    "sce0_pmax_score_aligned_03": 101,
    "sce0_pmax_score_aligned_04": -1252234954199944000,
    "sce0_pmax_score_aligned_05": 9201734396028061000
  }
}
```

So in the above input i have 2 types of array type fields, 1 normal array (sce0-*custom-numeric*-*field) and second fields inside an array (eg sce0-triad-score-*aligned inside sce0-behavior-scores). If we take the second case, i want the whole array under a single string in output, i.e. the whole array i want to map it to behavr_scr.

Can anyone help how i can achieve that in jolt itself.

I tried doing the below for the first scenario but there was no change.
https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/547